# Slow roasting potatoes

Tags: potatoes, slow-cooking, roasting

Is it possible to slow roast potatoes?

I am slow roasting a pork belly in the oven at 130c for 4 hours, can I add whole (small-medium sized) potatoes as well? Would they need the full 4 hours? How would it effect the end product (texture/taste/etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Cover them with hot oil, or pork or duck fat, then in the oven with the belly... you will have awesome confit potato. Add herbs or spices to the oil if you like...You could cut them or do them whole. Creamy and delicious.